# Unable to run a Java Program with the command line option -DsocksProxyHost

Tags: java, proxy

When I run a Java program with a command line option `-DsocksProxyHost 10.123.76.20`, I got an error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 10/123/76/20
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 10.123.76.20
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: 10.123.76.20.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-D` should be used as follows:

```
-DsocksProxyHost=10.123.76.20
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you put on your command line here.

To run a Java program from command line, you have to specify the class which you would like to be invoked.

Let's say your program is located in **c:\program\my.jar** and **com.myapp** is the full name of the class you want to run, you should do like this:

```
java -cp c:\program\my.jar com.myapp -DsocksProxyHost 10.123.76.20
```